# How do I translate a collection of points relative to one of an other pair of points being moved?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, geometry

I have two lists of points all on the same cartesian plane.

`Collection1` forms a complex shape (say a longish polygon with many points and sides but roughly rectangular overall).  `Collection2` has two points making a line that is (usually) inside of the first shape made by `Collection1`.  When a single point in `collection2` is moved I want to translate all the points in the `collection1 by the same amount.

Well not actually by the same amount I need the points (in `collection1`) that are closest to the point in `collection2` being moved to move a lot, and the points in `collection1` that are far away from the moving point in `collection2` to move very little.

Something like this,

Beginning:
[image]
Translated:
[image]

The problem is if you continue to move the point in `collection2` the shape slowly deforms until eventually it looks like this.
[image]

If the point in `collection2` is moved back to its original position then all the points in `collection` should be in their original spots as well.

I assume the reason for this odd issue is because I am using a weight to move points that closer to the moving point by more and points that are far away from it by a smaller weight.  The code is bellow.

How do I get the points to move or translate relative to how close they are to the moving point with out gradually deforming the original shape, or in other words points in `collection1` should not lose their relative distance from the points in `collection2`?

Bellow is what I think is the relevant code.

```
  fun moveSelectedBoneConstrained(x: Double, y: Double) {
    selectedBoneIndex?.let {
      val oldPoint = bones[it]
      val anchorPoint = if (it == 0) bones[1] else bones[0]
      var angle = Math.atan2((y - anchorPoint.y).toDouble(), (x - anchorPoint.x ).toDouble())
      val r = getDistance(oldPoint, anchorPoint)
      val cosX = Math.cos(angle)
      val sinY = Math.sin(angle)

      val newX = r * cosX
      val newY = r * sinY

      val newPoint = PointBig((anchorPoint.x + newX.toFloat()), anchorPoint.y + newY.toFloat())
      transmuteOutlineLinearWithDeltaWeight(oldPoint, newPoint, anchorPoint)
      //must change bones last
      bones[it] = newPoint
    }
  }
```

```
fun transmuteOutlineLinearWithDeltaWeight( oldPoint: PointBig, newPoint:      PointBig,anchorPoint: PointBig){
  val tempOutline = mutableListOf<PointBig>()
  var deltaX = newPoint.x - oldPoint.x
  var deltaY = newPoint.y - oldPoint.y
  outline.forEach {

    //get weight
    val distanceToOld = calculateDistance( it.x, it.y, oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y)
    val distanceToAnchor = calculateDistance( it.x, it.y, anchorPoint.x, anchorPoint.y)
    val sumDistance = distanceToOld + distanceToAnchor
    val weighting = distanceToAnchor/sumDistance
    //multiply by weight

    var newdeltaX = deltaX * weighting
    var newdeltaY = deltaY *  weighting

    val newX = it.x + newdeltaX
    newY = it.y + newdeltaY



    tempOutline.add(PointBig(newX, newY))
  }
  outline.clear()
  outline.addAll(tempOutline)

  }
  fun calculateDistance(x1: Double, y1: Double, x2: Double, y2: Double): Double {
    val xDiff = x2 - x1
    val yDiff = y2 - y1
    return kotlin.math.sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff))
 }
```

Thank you in advance! I'm pushing the boundaries of my intelligence here.

Comment: I didn't look very closely into your code, but from your description I think I know what's the problem. You should not simply replace positions of points with new ones. Instead, for both collections you should keep both the initial positions and current positions. Whenever you move a point you should only take into consideration what is its position in relation to the initial position and you should translate other points also from their initial positions, not their current positions. That should provide a natural feel of the "physics" and guarantee it always returns to the same shape.

Comment: @broot I could.  It seems cleaner to translate points based off of the most recent change.  I'd like to not have to start retaining an initial state and taking that into account.  I will experiment with it though.

Comment: There’s no way mathematically to do this without storing extra data for each point. Either it needs to be the starting point, the previous delta change (more complicated math), or maybe something else. But the current position alone doesn’t carry enough information to determine what you need.

Comment: The root problem here is that we treat the move as an instant "jump" and we use the same weight for the whole jump. After moving 10 to the right, then 10 to the left, other points won't return to same spots. Similarly, moving 1x10 results in a different state than 2x5. To make it work consistently, we can't treat it as jumps, but change the weight while the distance changes during the move. That means either some advanced calculus, or splitting the move into multiple very small moves. Translating from the initial position probably won't provide the same results, but it is an easy workaround.

Comment: You should be able to easily verify my hypothesis. Modify the code, so whenever you move a point, you take 1/1000th of the move vector and apply it 1000 times in a loop. I suspect it will give you move consistent results (still not 100% consistent). Of course, this is bad for CPU.

Comment: The images look like a [shear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping#Definition).

Comment: Shear can be combined with other [image transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Image_transformation) to get a variety of effects, all conveniently encoded in a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: @user3386109: This is a good idea. Since you would need 3 points to *uniquely* determine an affine transform but we only have 2, I think the most natural way to restrict the mapping would be to force it to be a composition of a rotation, uniform scaling in both directions, and translation (i.e., avoiding shear and reflections). There are then just 4 parameters (rotation angle, scaling factor, x and y offsets for the translation). The translation is just the translation of the *midpoint of* the original and final line segments; the angle and scale parameters are also easy to determine.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You are correct that `collection2` only has two points, and therefore its transform can be realized with only translation, rotation, and scaling. But `collection1` is clearly being sheared. So my impression is that the OP hasn't fully and precisely described the problem. The problem reminds me of [image animations based on skeletal physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation). If that's what the OP is actually trying to do, then there is no simple solution.

Comment: @user3386109: I agree that the example figure looks like shearing -- but my gut feeling is that OP will discover (as soon as they try moving one endpoint of `collection2` around more, e.g., to make a horizontal line segment) that shearing isn't what they actually want...

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's a good point, and I agree. The problem description is incomplete.